# How can I create a checkbox form with array values

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have got an array with strings and I want to create a form with checkboxes, where each string has it´s own checkbox. The function `$Service->read_command_cfg();` returns the correct array.

My PHP Code is as follows:

```
<form action="host_add.php" method = "post" >
<?PHP
include_once('service.php');
echo'Services:';
if (!empty($_POST['host_select']))
{
  $Service = new Service;
  $array_command_name_new = $Service->read_command_cfg();
}

foreach($array_command_name_new as $key=>$value)
{
  echo'<p><input type="checkbox" name="'.$value.'" value="'.$value.'/>' .$value. '</p>';    
}
?>
</form>
```

I got the following HTML-Output:

```
<form action="host_add.php" method = "post" >
Services:<p><input type="checkbox" name="command_name   notify-host" value="command_name notify-host/>command_name  notify-host</p><p><input type="checkbox" name="command_name notify-service" value="command_name notify-service/>command_name    notify-service</p>
</form>
```

On the Website I got only one checkbutton without text.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Your html shows two checkboxes. I don't think I understand the problem.

Comment: You're missing a quote from `value="' . $value . '"`

Comment: Nevermind, I think @billyonecan just nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error -

```
foreach($array_command_name_new as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='$value' value='$value' />$value</p>";
}
```